# How to transform dictionaries containing lists to specific rows?

Tags: python, dictionary, transformation, export-to-csv, python-2.6

I've got Python script like:

```
for row in file:
    ....
    ....
    ....
    whole_calendar = {}
    whole_calendar['ID'] = id
    whole_calendar['OPEN'] = open_days
    whole_calendar['CLOSED'] = closed_days
    whole_calendar['CHECKED'] = checked_days
    print(whole_calendar)
```

that generates (iterates over) a lot of similar dictionary rows:

```
{'ID': ['133528'], 'OPEN': ['1/1/2016', '2/1/2016', '3/1/2016', '4/1/2016'], 'CLOSED': ['5/1/2016'], 'CHECKED': ['1/7/2016']}

{'ID': ['176987'], 'OPEN': ['3/6/2016', 4/6/2016'], 'CLOSED': [], 'CHECKED': ['1/7/2016',2/7/2016]}

{'ID': ['347697'], 'OPEN': ['1/2/2016'], 'CLOSED': ['1/3/2016'], 'CHECKED': []}
```

What I need is write these dictionaries (rows) to the CSV file in the form of this table ->

```
133528,'OPEN','1/1/2016'
133528,'OPEN','2/1/2016'
133528,'OPEN','3/1/2016'
133528,'OPEN','4/1/2016'
133528,'CLOSED','5/1/2016'
133528,'CHECKED','1/7/2016'
176987,'OPEN','3/6/2016'
176987,'OPEN','4/6/2016'
176987,'CHECKED','1/7/2016'
176987,'CHECKED','2/7/2016'
347697,'OPEN','1/2/2016'
347697,'CLOSED','1/3/2016'
```

I need to use just built-ins libraries in Python 2.6 (no Pandas)

I've tried some transformations + using csv.writerow but I can't do it.
Can you help me here please?

Comment: the desired output might not always be in that order because it is a dictionary so unordered...

Comment: This is not the problem. I will read it as CSV from another software :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are complicating things with the intermediary dictionary step.  You could just write the new file as you read lines from the old file.

```
import csv

with open('new_format.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['id', 'status', 'date']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    for row in file:
        ....
        ....
        ....
        [writer.writerow({'id': id, 'status': 'OPEN', 'date': d}) for d in open_days]
        [writer.writerow({'id': id, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'date': d}) for d in closed_days]
        [writer.writerow({'id': id, 'status': 'CHECKED', 'date': d}) for d in checked_days]
```

Comment: There are just two things I had to change. I've deleted the square brackets around the expressions and i've used writer.writerows instead of writer.writerow because it wrote out that my dictionary contains different fieldnames than my writer. I dont understand why
and i dont also understand why it generates blank row after each one but it works now. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, Now it works in the same manner as "my version" with write.writerows...
Can you explain me, how the square brackets around the function works? I don´t know where to look in documentation...

Comment: It's a list comprehension.  Very handy, you should learn about them: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Answer (score 0):

Andrew's answer doesn't 100% work for me but after i've made small changes:

```
import csv

with open('new_format.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['id', 'status', 'date']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    for row in file:
        ....
        ....
        ....
        writer.writerows({'id': id, 'status': 'OPEN', 'date': d} for d in open_days)
        writer.writerows({'id': id, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'date': d} for d in closed_days)
        writer.writerows({'id': id, 'status': 'CHECKED', 'date': d} for d in checked_days)
```

it does and it looks almost right (i don´t know why i get blank rows):

```
    ...
    8: 4882410,CLOSED,2016-11-09
    9:
    10: 4882410,CLOSED,2016-11-10
    11:
    12: 4882410,CLOSED,2016-11-11
    ...
```